# Laravel get Model by Table Name

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to get a model by table name?

For example, I have a "User" model, its table is defined as `protected $table = "users"`

Now, what I want to do is to get the model by table name which is equal to "users".

This function is more like the reverse of `Model::getTable();`

I have searched everywhere but I could not find a solution, perhaps I might be missing something simple?

**EDIT**

I am building something like an API :

```
Route::get('/{table}', 'ApiController@api');
Route::get('/{table}/filter', 'ApiController@filter');
Route::get('/{table}/sort', 'ApiController@sort');
Route::get('/{table}/search', 'ApiController@search');
```

so in the address bar, for example when I search for the "users", I could just hit on the URL:

```
api/users/search?id=1
```

then on the controller, something like:

```
public function search(){
  // get all the params

  // get the model function
  $model = //function to get model by table name

  // do some filtering, then return the model
  return $model;
}
```

Comment: can tell us what you want to do? because what comes in my mind is something like inheritance and dependency inversion when i see such a question

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja I have edited my question. Thank you

Comment: keep in mind, a well formatted question results in better answers , i hope you find the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 18):

Maybe something like this will help you:

```
$className = 'App\\' . studly_case(str_singular($tableName));

if(class_exists($className)) {
    $model = new $className;
}
```

Comment: thank you Igor :) This is possible if my table name is the same as the name of the model's class.

Comment: But in other way you cannot get $table for model class without creating an instance, as $table variable is protected and you cannot access it statically. Without changing core Model class you cannot do that

Comment: I get your point. Hmm, so Laravel doesn't have something like CoreModel::getModelByTableName(string)

Comment: no, it has no awareness that those classes are even models, they are just classes.

Comment: Laravel 6 - The following work for me : 
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
.....
$className = 'App\\' . Str::studly(str::singular($tableName)); if(class_exists($className)) { 
  $model = new $className; 
}

Answer (score 5):

`studly_case()` and `str_singular()` are deprecated functions.

You can use the `Illuminate\Support\Str` facade.

```
$className = 'App\\' . Str::studly(Str::singular($tableName));
```

Answer (score 3):

I know that it is an old question, but it can help someone:

```
public function getModelFromTable($table)
{
    foreach( get_declared_classes() as $class ) {
        if( is_subclass_of( $class, 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model' ) ) {
            $model = new $class;
            if ($model->getTable() === $table)
                return $class;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It will return the class name, so you need to instantiate it.

Comment: Doesn't include Models unfortunately.

Comment: It does support Models but the ones that are initialised. Simple include (use) does not help, the model has to be called.

Answer (score 2):

You must determine for which table name which class to call.
I see 2 ways to do this.

Use Laravel's models naming convention as @IgorRynkovoy suggested

or

Use some kind of dictionary

```
public function search($tableName)
{
    $dictionary = [
        'table_name' => 'CLASS_NAME_WITH_NAMESPACE',
        'another_table_name' => 'CLASS_NAME_WITH_NAMESPACE',
    ];

    $className = $dictionary[$tableName];
    $models = null;

    if(class_exists($className)) {
        $models = $className::all();
    }

    // do some filtering, then return the model
    return $models;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative variant.
I have my base model App\Models\Model
This model have static method getModelByTable, ofcourse you can store this method anywhere you want.

```
public static function getModelByTable($table)
    {
        if (!$table) return false;
        $model = false;
        switch ($table) {
            case 'faq':
                $model = Faq::class;
                break;
            case 'faq_items':
                $model = FaqItems::class;
                break;
        }
        if ($model) {
            try {
                $model = app()->make($model);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {

            }
        }
        return $model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from the following, instead of from Model.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class EnhancedModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model. Copies $table in Model
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected static string $tableName;

    /**
     * Get the table associated with the model. Copies getTable() in Model
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getTableName(): string
    {
        return static::$tableName ?? Str::snake(Str::pluralStudly(class_basename(static::class)));
    }

    /**
     * Get the table associated with the model. Overrides getTable() in Model
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTable(): string
    {
        return $this::getTableName();
    }
}
```

To override the auto-guessed table name, add this to your EnhancedModel descendent class:

```
protected static string $tableName = 'the_table_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks Laravel 6 make some changes.  The following works fine for me

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Str;
    ....
    $className = 'App\\' . Str::studly(str::singular($table_name));
       if(class_exists($className)) {
        $model = new $className; 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old but if it can help someone.
I made this from [@Marcus Christiansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3605760/marcus-christiansen) example.
I guess you can adapt the string output to your needs like adding strtolower() should you have capitals in your table names.

Just make sure your models and table names respect the typography ModelName / table_name

```php
/**
     * Return a new instance of a model given the proper related table name.
     * @param $tableName
     * @return false|mixed
     */
    public function getModelByTableName( $tableName ): mixed
    {
        $className = 'App\\Models\\' . Str::studly( Str::singular( $tableName ));

        if( class_exists( $className )) {
            return new $className;
        }
        return false;
    }
```