# Laravel - How to know which models are related to a specific model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-7

I would like to know the models that are related to my table.

Is there a method to do it like this ?

```
        $model    = new $model;
        $table    = $model->getTable();
        $columns  = Schema::getColumnListing($table);
```

For example like this ?

```
       $model->relationships()
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: There's no reliable way to do that specially if the class name doesn't follow standard naming scheme, but please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/37513558/407412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box there is no way to do it, you have to come up with your own solution. You can try this here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/get-all-model-relationships